# What web service to use for complicate query?

Tags: web-services, rest, post, soap

A naive question about web service.

I need to implement a complicate query. The client need to pass in many parameters to the server, and the server will send back response will many data fields.

What type of web service is suitable for this? I know that RESTful POST method is meant to "create" an object, but can I use POST for implementing this?

Or SOAP is better for this?

Comment: Will you be using MVC and jQuery?

Comment: JQuery will be used in frontend. and MVC will be used on server side. Sorry, not sure why this matters.

Comment: because I have a working sample to paste usinng jquery and MVC do you want it or just asking a question?

Comment: @agentpx A working example would be great! Thank you very much!

Comment: is MVC and JQuery that popular for web services? :-)

Comment: @Leo I also use java in android application. I don't know exactly what you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is.

//for the Controller

```
    public JsonResult GetData(string param1, string param2)            
    {
        List<YourModecClass> data = new List<YourlModelClass>();

            //Mockup data only...you should get the data from DB source
            data = new List<YourModelClass>();
            data.Add(new YourModelClass() { Region = "", Value_TY = 0});
            data.Add(new YourModelClass() { Region = "", Value_TY = 0 });
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }
```

//jQuery

```
function getServerData() {
var entity = { 
    param1: param1 //--> ths is a variable
    param2: "value" //--> hardcoded
}
var parameter = JSON.stringify(entity); 

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url + "/GetData",  
    data: parameter,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    async: true,
    beforeSend: function () {
    },
    success: function (response, status, xhr) {
        yourJavascriptVariable = response;
        doSomethingWithreceivedDataAbove();
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        debugger;
    }
});
```