# Call controller method from javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, xml, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to call the controller method from `jquery` call. Here is my `code`.

```
<script>
function showImage(id) {
    $.get('/Canvas/getPath?id=' + id, function (data) {
        if (data != '') {
            var ext = /[^.]+$/.exec(data);
            var filename = data;
            if(ext == 'tif')
            {                    
                //window.open('/DocViewer/DocViewer.aspx?FilePath=' + data, 'WindowPopup', 'height=auto,width=auto,status=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');
                window.open('/DocViewer/DocViewer.aspx', 'WindowPopup', 'height=auto,width=auto,status=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');
            }
            else if(ext == 'xml'){
                $.ajax('/Canvas/getXml?filePath=' + filename, function (xmldata) {
                    alert(xmldata);
                    window.open(xmldata, "WindowPopup", 'height=auto,width=auto,status=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');
                }); 
            }
        }
        else {
            alert('Document does not exists. Please make sure the document is on location.');
        }
    });
};
</script>
```

### Edit

Here is my controller method

```
    public JsonResult getXml(string filePath)
    {
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            string xmlString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            return Json(xmlString, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); ;
        }
        else
        {
            return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Here what I want if `ext` if xml then I want to call the `method` of `controller`. In above code it gives me error on `new { filePath = filename }` filename doesn't exists. Basically I trying to open **xml file** in browser. In data I receive the **filePath** of xml file. How can I call controller method or open xml file in browser?

Comment: You are opening a file from local system. Which in browser security practice is not permitted unless it came from uploaded file. If we can do this then all of us developer can access users file locally.

Comment: That's why I am trying to call the controller method which return xml string. so that I can show it in browser

Comment: A better approach is to parse your XML and return the content as XML or JSON to the client and not the file itself.

Comment: Yes same I want to implement. But I can't call controller method inside else block

Comment: @agentpx How can I call controller method inside `else if` block?

Comment: url needs to be javascript string when it is output (quoted) and `$.get` can't be written long hand the way `$.ajax` can. Read the docs

Comment: If I call `$.ajax` or `$.get` inside else if block my old code isn't work.

Comment: @agentpx I just done some changes in my question. check else if method. Right it is calling the method `getXml` but it doesn't show the alert popup

Comment: I have similar answer on calling controller method using jquey AJAX call. It is a working sample and feel free to modify it to suit your needs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27608850/what-web-service-to-use-for-complicate-query/27609179#27609179

Comment: @charlietfl Hey friend my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys my problem is solved. Here my full `script`

```
<script>
function showImage(id) {
    $.getJSON('/Canvas/getPath?id=' + id, function (data) {
        if (data != '') {
            var ext = /[^.]+$/.exec(data);
            var filename = data;
            if(ext == 'tif')
            {
                //window.open('/DocViewer/DocViewer.aspx?FilePath=' + data, 'WindowPopup', 'height=auto,width=auto,status=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');
                window.open('/DocViewer/DocViewer.aspx', 'WindowPopup', 'height=auto,width=auto,status=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');
            }
            else if(ext == 'xml'){                    
                $.getJSON('/Canvas/getXml?filePath=' + filename, function (xmldata) {
                    alert(xmldata);
                    window.open('data:text/xml,' + encodeURIComponent(xmldata), "WindowPopup", 'height=auto,width=auto,status=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');
                });                    
            }
        }
        else {
            alert('Document does not exists. Please make sure the document is on location.');
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Action("getXml", "Canvas")'+'?filePath'+=filename,
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(data) 
      { 
      alert(data); 
      }
});
```

Your code is not working and giving parameter undefined because you are mixing javascript and razor method call.

```
function showImage(id) {
    $.get('/Canvas/getPath?id=' + id, function (data) {
        if (data != '') {
            var ext = /[^.]+$/.exec(data);
            var filename = data;
            if(ext == 'tif')
            {                    
                //window.open('/DocViewer/DocViewer.aspx?FilePath=' + data, 'WindowPopup', 'height=auto,width=auto,status=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');
                window.open('/DocViewer/DocViewer.aspx', 'WindowPopup', 'height=auto,width=auto,status=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');
            }
            else if(ext == 'xml'){
                $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("getXml", "Canvas")'+'?filePath'+=filename,
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(data) 
                { 
                alert(data); 
                }
                });
                //window.open(data, "WindowPopup", 'height=auto,width=auto,status=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');
            }
        }
        else {
            alert('Document does not exists. Please make sure the document is on location.');
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Where should I put this? inside else block?

Comment: Yes. you have to put over there to get that link work

Comment: I want to call it only if file `ext` is `xml`. In else if block. If I call it in inside `else if`. Then code doesn't work.

Comment: Yes. you have to put over else if block where you check that extension is xml. Problem is part of code not entire code.

Comment: @dotnetstep I update my code to yours. But I doesn't work. My old code also doesn't work. Is it possible to define `$.ajax` inside `$.get`

Comment: Yes. It is not inside that. It is on success call of that. Can you please check viewsource browser and put some update as it is working my side.

Comment: Correct and please add  contentType: "application/xml"inside $.ajax call

Comment: @dotnetstep I just done some changes in my question. check else if method. Right it is calling the method `getXml` but it doesn't show the alert popup

Comment: I have a similar answer to calling controller method via AJAX here it is. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27608850/what-web-service-to-use-for-complicate-query/27609179#27609179

Comment: You have used $ajax different way. Use the way I have suggested as It works for me.

Comment: Good to hear that @AjayPunekar :D